# Applet deployment javafx 2.2, firefox, ubuntu

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, applet, javafx, java-7

I try to have my javafx applet working under Firefox, Ubuntu 12.04 x64, using JDK 1.7u10 b06 x64

*The test on this page works* (but doesn't use javafx): 
http://technonstop.com/install-java-plugin-ubuntu-linux

*This one doesn't* :
http://privatewww.essex.ac.uk/~wsomba/ParticleFx.html
=> I'm asked to install Java.

I think I set up properly the firefox plugin (amd64)
*Firefox about:plugins* :

```
Java Plug-in 1.7.0_10

Fichier : libnpjp2.so
Version : 
Java plug-in for NPAPI-based browsers.

Type MIME     Description     Suffixes
application/x-java-vm     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet     Java™ Plug-in Applet     
application/x-java-bean     Java™ Plug-in JavaBeans     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.3     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.3     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.4     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.4     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.5     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.5     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.6     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.6     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;version=1.7     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;version=1.7     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.7.0_10     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.7.0_10     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;deploy=10.10.2     Java™ Plug-in     
application/x-java-applet;javafx=2.2.2     Java™ Plug-in
```

*Javascript platform validation* :

```
function check(){
var platform = new dtjava.Platform(
       {
           jvm : '1.7.0_06+',
           javafx : '2.2+',
       }
    );
    if (dtjava.validate(platform)!=null){
      alert(dtjava.validate(platform));
    }
}
```

==> alert :

```
MISMATCH [os=false, browser=false, jre=none, fx=ok, relaunch=false, platform=Platform [jvm=1.7.0_06+, javafx=2.2+, plugin=*, jvmargs=null]]
```

I read many advices to make it work, most of them were outdated...
Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I followed the instructions for installing the jre (7u7) on linux (Centos 6.3) and enabling a java plugin in Firefox (10.0.7) and it worked fine for your ParticleFx link as well as the JavaFX [sample applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html).  Perhaps you have a 32 bit firefox and are trying to use it with a 64 bit jvm plugin => which won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applets in 7u10 are temporarily broken, pending integration of:
http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24875 "Can not load javafx applets using 7u10 builds"

> The issue is that dtjava.js treats 7u10 as something lower than 7u6 (due to lexicographical comparison).

Comment: Thank you, it appears to be right. Note that changing symbolic link for firefox plugin resulted for me in a strange state where about:plugins shown me the right version (7u7) but test applets used the 7u10. Don't know why, some cache I had to work around.